# CouchDB filtering metadata during sync

Tags: android, couchdb

I'm thinking of using couchDB in one of my android applications. I've designed a basic application looking into couchdb tutorial. Couchbase server has been setup. When I replicate the data, I can see 3 documents per replication.

```
 1. 78e2c7dc-da9a-42f4-95a6-03bd6cea7b6e    { "_sync": { "rev":
"1-5aca82e9-e4cc-47db-9cce-fe32fea68d1c", "sequence": 1, "history":
{ "revs": [ "1-5aca82e9-e4cc-47db-9cce-fe32fea68d1c" ], "parents": [
-1 ], "bodies": [ "" ], "channels": [ null ] }, "time_saved": "2014-04-26T14:58:37.399871861+05:30" }, "check": false,
"created_at": "25-04-14", "text": "huhahhahhahah" }  
Delete Edit Document
_sync:local:a7e278f189bb5954e0bae030cf2dd2b231a7318e    { "_rev": "0-1", "lastSequence": "1" }   
Delete Edit Document
_sync:seq   4
```

I need to know how to filter this meta data from getting replicated. All I need from the above data is the "check, created_at, text" attributes. I did some research. All I could found is that I've to ignore _sync properties during sync. But I could not get how to do this.